# Display previous year

Tags: django-templates

I need to display previous year in the django template. I know I can do `{% now "Y" %}` and `{{ var|add:"-1" }}` but I don't know how to connect these two. Can that be done without the custom template?

Answer (score 1):

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now :

> You can also use the syntax `{% now "Y" as current_year %}` to store the output (as a string) inside a variable. This is useful if you want to use `{% now %}` inside a template tag like blocktranslate for example:

```
{% now "Y" as current_year %}
{% blocktranslate %}Copyright {{ current_year }}{% endblocktranslate %}
```